# Microsoft TFS occasionally not sending email confirmation after check in

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I regularly check in the changes as I always normally do, but sometimes simply I don't get an email confirmation even though the checked in changes are visible on the server.

I was wandering if there was any particular reason why roughly every 15th check in is not triggering an email confirmation?

Comment: Is there any condition that in common for the emails that won't send? I mean the issue happens during a certain time or a particular team project or something else? How about other team members? Are they have the same experience?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Not really, it's pretty random. The other team members are experiencing the same issue as well as myself.

Comment: It's hard for us to troubleshooting your issue as there is no error log. You may check the network or firewall on your SMTP server to see if there is a block.